# Multiple dropdown menu's with same name select the value by index

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu

I've created a for loop that creates an amount of dropdown menu's depending on a variable. The options are coming from the database. Like this:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i< $variable; $i++)
   <select name="name[]">
   @for ($x = 0; $x< $variable2; $x++)
      <option value={{$result[$x]->columname}}>something</option>
   @endfor
   </select>
@endfor
```

So basically when the `$variable=3` there will be 3 dropdown menu's with the same options. Now whenever there are values in some dropdown menu's and the person clicks the button, I want the variables to stay in it. I know I can use `selected` but I have no idea how to make sure it stays on the right option in the right dropdown menu.

Now whenever I `var_dump('name');` I get to see all the option value's of the existing dropdown menu's in  an array. So of course I send back the `Input::get('name')` from the **controller** to the **view** like: `return View::make('page')->with('name',Input::get('name'));`

My question is, how would I actually be able to get the values to stay in the dropdown menu they were in before with the Input value I have right now?

Comment: here you can use html array concept.

Comment: _there will be 3 dropdown menu's with the same options_ and same `name` as well.

Comment: @Ejay Sorry I forgot something on here. Look at the edit.